# Getting SNAP AOP Framework working with Ninject MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, aop, ninject.web.mvc

I want to try out so SOA style logging using Snap in my MVC3 application. I'm using Ninject for IoC so have installed Ninject.MVC and Snap.Ninject via Nuget all had a look at the sample code in GitHub for Snap.Ninject. I also read [Getting SNAP(AOP), NInject and ASP.Net MVC 3 working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157375/getting-snapaop-ninject-and-asp-net-mvc-3-working-together/5168271#5168271)
which seems to be doing exactly what I want.

I've updated my NinjctMVC3.cs accordingly but when I add the interceptor attribute to my method, I get an object ref error from Snap AspectUtility. Here is my NinjectMVC3.cs

```
    public static class NinjectMVC3 {
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(HttpApplicationInitializationModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop() {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel() {
        //var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        NinjectAopConfiguration.NinjectAopConfigure();
        var kernel = NinjectAopConfiguration._container.Kernel;
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {

        kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<NLogger>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("currentClassName", x => x.Request.ParentContext.Request.Service.FullName); ;
        kernel.Bind<ISomeDataFactory>().To<SomeDataFactory>();
    }
}

public static class NinjectAopConfiguration {
    public readonly static NinjectAspectContainer _container;

    static NinjectAopConfiguration() {
        _container = new NinjectAspectContainer();
    }
    public static void NinjectAopConfigure() {
        SnapConfiguration.For(_container).Configure(c => {
            c.IncludeNamespace("TestAopLogging.Model.*");
            c.Bind<MyMethodInterceptor>().To<MyInterceptorAttribute>();
        });
    }
}

public class MyMethodInterceptor : MethodInterceptor {
    public override void InterceptMethod(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation, MethodBase method, System.Attribute attribute) {
        var logger = new NLogger(method.DeclaringType.ToString());
        logger.LogInfo("Hello AOP Logger. Your method (" + method.Name + ") has been intercepted");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }

    public override void BeforeInvocation() {
        var logger = new NLogger("How do I work out what class I'm in?");
        base.BeforeInvocation();
    }

    public override void AfterInvocation() {
        var logger = new NLogger("How do I work out what class I'm in?");
        logger.LogInfo("Hello AOP Logger. After Invocation");
        base.AfterInvocation();
    }
}

public class MyInterceptorAttribute : MethodInterceptAttribute { }
```

And the controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    private ISomeDataFactory _someDataFactory;

    public HomeController(ILogger logger, ISomeDataFactory someDataFactory) {
        _logger = logger;
        _someDataFactory = someDataFactory;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInfo("I've hit the index action");
        _someDataFactory.GetStuffAndLogTheOldWay();
        _someDataFactory.GetStuffAndLogUsingAOP();
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and the factory class with the method with the intercept attribute

```
public interface ISomeDataFactory {
    string GetStuffAndLogTheOldWay();
    string GetStuffAndLogUsingAOP();
}

public class SomeDataFactory : ISomeDataFactory {
    private ILogger _logger;

    public SomeDataFactory(ILogger logger) {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string GetStuffAndLogTheOldWay() {
        _logger.LogInfo(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " was called");
        return "I called GetStuffAndLogTheOldWay";
    }

    [MyInterceptor] // If I comment this out, then all is good
    public string GetStuffAndLogUsingAOP() {
        return "I called GetStuffAndLogUsingAOP";
    }
}
```

and this results in the following exception

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Snap.AspectUtility.CreateProxy(Type interfaceType, Object instanceToWrap, IInterceptor[] interceptors) +29
   Snap.AspectUtility.CreatePseudoProxy(IMasterProxy proxy, Type interfaceType, Object instanceToWrap) +184
   Snap.Ninject.AspectProxyActivationStrategy.Activate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) +376
   Ninject.Activation.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IActivationStrategy s) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:58
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:23
   Ninject.Activation.Pipeline.Activate(IContext context, InstanceReference reference) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Pipeline.cs:58
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:182
   Ninject.KernelBase.b__7(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:375
   System.Linq.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x) +32
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4178557
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:179
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:147
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:97
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Create>b__1(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:81
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +325
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:81
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__7(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:375
   System.Linq.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x) +32
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4178557
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:56
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +51

Thanks in advance. I want a working demo of it failing then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tyler Brinks for spotting my typo!

Update the namespace reference to

c.IncludeNamespace("TestAopLogging.Models.*");

and all is well.

Hope someone finds this useful.